# Why does my private variable equal zero when I overload the array operator?

Tags: c++, class, methods

I'm writing a program with a class named MyInteger that stores an integer and has functions to get and set the integer's value. Then I have to overload the [] operator so that the index returns the digit in position i, where i=0 is the least significant digit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class MyInteger
{
public:

    MyInteger();
    MyInteger(int n);
    int& operator[](int index);
    void setNumber(int);
    int getTotalDigits();
    int getNumber() const;


private:
    int number;
    int totalDigits;
    int digitArray[20];
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, MyInteger&);
};

int main()
{
    MyInteger b(4);

    cout << b.getNumber() << endl;

    return 0;
}

MyInteger::MyInteger() : number(0)
{

}

MyInteger::MyInteger(int n) :number(n)
{

}

int MyInteger::getNumber() const
{
    return number;
}

void MyInteger::setNumber(int n)
{
    number = n;
}

int MyInteger::getTotalDigits()
{
    totalDigits = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (number > 0)
    {
        number = number / 10;
        totalDigits++;
    }

    return totalDigits;
}


ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, MyInteger& I)
{
    outputStream << I.getNumber();

    return outputStream;
}

int& MyInteger:: operator [](int index)
{
    getTotalDigits();
    cout << number << endl; // This comes out to be zero
    digitArray[totalDigits - 1] = number*pow(10, totalDigits - 1);
    for (int i = totalDigits - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        digitArray[i - i] = digitArray[i] * pow(10, totalDigits - 1);
    }

    return digitArray[index];

}
```

When I try to access the private variable `number` in the overloaded function definition `[]`, it outputs zero. Why is that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It would be better design to not have `totalDigits` as a member variable; and the operator[] and other functions should use the return value of `getTotalDigits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member function `getTotalDigits` changes the private data member `number`

```
int MyInteger::getTotalDigits()
{
    totalDigits = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (number > 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        number = number / 10;
        totalDigits++;
    }

    return totalDigits;
}
```

A correct its implementation can be

```
int MyInteger::getTotalDigits() const
{
    totalDigits = 0;

    int value = number;

    do { totalDigits++; } while ( value /= 10 );

    return totalDigits;
}
```

Also the overloaded `operator []` itself does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know that overloaded operator doesn't make sense. I was able to fix it. Thank you again